# What is the reason of the existence of Gitlab Web Interface that can creates folder, branch,etc?

Tags: version-control, gitlab

I hope my elementary question is not a duplicate. I'm very new to gitlab and other source control management system. I created a project on gitlab and added some directories and files using web IDE.
My question is:

1-why there is such a GUI feature in Gitlab to create branches, directories,etc?
I always thought that i always create my project LOCALLY and then push it to my remote repository and it seems to me strange to work (write codes, add branches,...) directly on remote repository.
Does it mean we can work on a project with gitlab without even needing to have a LOCAL repository? and we do all the development process through the GUI?

2-When we have a LOCAL repository on which we develop, is there any need to use gitlab web Interface for any reason?

3-I noticed that all the stuff that i do through web Gui is committed. So these Commits on GUI side will be merged to the LOCAL committed that i do on my LOCAL repository on my PC?

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience you can indeed work in the gitlab GUI for small changes, however pushing a project is much easier if you work locally. If you want to merge your local branch with changes you've made through the GUI you have to use a few commands first.

If branch B is at local, You can merge A to B locally and push B to remote:

```
git checkout B
git merge A
git push origin B
```

If you don't have B at local, you can push A to remote and pull request to merge A to B and click merge button on gitlab.

or, fetch B branch to local and merge A to B , then push B to remote, like this:

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin B:B      (fetch B to local)
git checkout B            (checkout to branch B)
git merge A               (merge A to B)
git push origin B         (push merged branch B to remote)
```

I hope this brought you some insight, let me know if there's anything I can do better in the future.

Comment: Thank you, but for even small projects, do i need to have a local repository? it seems to me from Gitlab interface, that i don't even need to have a local repo. I can develop my code using commits (available on the web interface) and then build my project inside gitlab.

Comment: I mean Gitlab web interface with its IDE to write codes, and buttons to add branches and directories are enough for small projects or it accompanies the local development, build and test?

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: Hi there, I was gone for a little bit but I did do some research to Gitlab's online IDE. I think it's definitely possible to work on your project within their online IDE. I think it mostly comes down to preferences. I myself have been programming in VS Code for 5 years now and I can't live without the specific plugins I've been using. But over all, working in their online IDE will be more simplified for people who aren't very familiar with how GIT bash works.

Answer (score 1):

Note: [GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#experience-the-web-ide-beta-and-remote-development) (December 2022) officializes the new environment:

> ### Experience the Web IDE Beta and Remote Development
>
> We are thrilled to announce the availability of the Web IDE Beta, our next-generation web editor based on Visual Studio Code that delivers powerful new features, a more flexible and familiar interface, and the ability to connect directly to a Remote Development environment.
> Paired with a cloud runtime, the Web IDE Beta enables more advanced real-time development workflows. Take a look at just some of the new features available today!
>
> The Web IDE Beta is so powerful we’re making it the default Web IDE experience for GitLab.com, and we’re eager for your feedback. The Web IDE will continue to be available while we iterate on the Beta.
> To stop using the Web IDE Beta, go to your [user preferences](https://gitlab.com/-/profile/preferences#web-ide) and select the **`Opt out of the Web IDE Beta`** checkbox.
>
> Self-managed instances have access to the Web IDE Beta where it is behind a [feature flag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/web_ide_beta/) disabled by default in GitLab 15.7.
>
> Learn more about the Web IDE Beta and what’s coming next in our [recent blog post](/blog/2022/12/15/get-ready-for-new-gitlab-web-ide/).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/web_ide_beta/) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/9189).

[image: web IDE]

---

The OP adds:

> But for even small projects, do I need to have a local repository?
> It seems to me from Gitlab interface, that i don't even need to have a local repo.

The [blog post](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2022/12/15/get-ready-for-new-gitlab-web-ide/) confirms:

> Developers and non-developers alike need to be able to contribute from anywhere, across multiple projects, and without context switching or the need to manage a local development environment.
>
> By connecting the Web IDE to a cloud runtime environment, you can unlock the full potential of a web-based IDE without having to manage your own local environment (see [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/remote_development/)).